# Saving dropzone.js files to local storage?

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

Is it possible to store dropzone.js files in local storage? I read the docs and looked all around the web for examples but there were none, so it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is posible. The part that you have to understand is that dropzone.js gives you the user experience, how you handle the docs or images in your server side is something different. You can try using ajax.

For example if you are using C# you have to handle how and where is going to be saved those docs. You need to define a folder in your disk where those docs are going to be stored.

Comment: I defined a folder in the url method and it returned a cannot post error eventhough the path was correct

Comment: Those the inspector gives you any more details about the error? Can you provide some code so I can check it?